# how to limit iis site bandwidth less than 1024kb

Tags: iis, iis-8, iis-10

I need limit one site bandwidth less than 100kb ,i tried set IIS maxBandWidth to 1024 and restart iis service ,but the speed still > 1M/s , What can I do the configuration. like nginx config.

```
location / {
  limit_conn one 1;
  limit_rate 100k;
}
```

my applicationHost.config is

```xml
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.applicationHost>
    ...
    <sites>
      <site name="mydomain.com" id="9">
          <application path="/" applicationPool="mydomain.com">
              <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\websites\mydomain.com" />
          </application>
          <bindings>
              <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:mydomain.com" />
              <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:mydomain.com" sslFlags="1" />
          </bindings>
          <applicationDefaults preloadEnabled="true" />
          <limits maxBandwidth="1024" maxConnections="1000" />
      </site>
    </sites>
  ...
  </system.applicationHost>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Show your IIS config file. Due to the complexity of IIS configuration system, you might have changed a wrong setting.

Comment: @Lex Li  <limits maxBandwidth="1024" maxConnections="1000" />

Comment: There are several places to put `<limits>` if you didn't know. That's why I asked for the actual config file, not just a single line.

Comment: @LexLi  ok , i put the config file now.

Comment: If this bandwidth limit does not work, you can try to install Windows Packet Scheduler. For more information about maxBandwidth in IIS, you can refer to this link: https://forums.iis.net/t/1247310.aspx?Limits+Bandwidth+Usage

Comment: not work also , i installed nginx, use iis proxy to nginx. limit rules configure in nginx.conf file now.

Comment: have you taken a look at the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits. Make sure to recycle apppool and restart app.